# Modify constraint programatically using SnapKit in Swift 3 to remove one UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, snapkit

I'm modifying the constraint of UIView height consist of nameTextField and its superView inputContainerView using SnapKit. I arrange the height of nameTextField is equal to one-third of the inputContainerView's height. My purpose is to remove the nameTextField when SegmentedControl is pressed.
When I try to modify the constant, it worked perfectly. 
But when I try to modify the multiplier height value from (1/3) to 0, sometimes it crashed and sometimes the other textField that I wrote (passwordTextField and emailTextField) is vanished.
I'm using updateContraint to update some of the constraint.
How am I supposed to fix this? Thank you

```
inputContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerX.equalTo(view.snp.centerX)
        make.centerY.equalTo(view.snp.centerY)
        // constraintAnchor is equal to offset
        make.width.equalTo(view.snp.width).offset(-24)
        make.height.equalTo(150)
    }

    // constraint for nameTextField
    inputContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
    //x y width height constraint using Snap Kit
    nameTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.left).offset(12)
        make.top.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.top)
        make.width.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.width)
        make.height.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.333)
    }
func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
    let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    // change height of inputcontainerview
    if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        inputContainerView.snp.updateConstraints({ (update) in
            update.height.equalTo(100)
        })
        nameTextField.snp.remakeConstraints({ (remake) in
            remake.height.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.height).multipliedBy(0)
        })
    } else if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        inputContainerView.snp.updateConstraints({ (update) in
            update.height.equalTo(150)
        })
        nameTextField.snp.remakeConstraints({ (remake) in
            remake.height.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.333)
        })
    }
}
// constraint for nameSeparator
    inputContainerView.addSubview(nameSeparator)
    //x y width height constraint using Snap Kit
    nameSeparator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.left).offset(12)
        make.top.equalTo(nameTextField.snp.bottom)
        make.right.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.right).offset(-12)
        make.height.equalTo(1)
    }

    // constraint for emailTextField
    inputContainerView.addSubview(emailTextField)
    //x y width height constraint using Snap Kit
    emailTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.left).offset(12)
        make.top.equalTo(nameSeparator.snp.bottom)
        make.width.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.width)
        make.height.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.333)
    }

    // constraint for emailSeparator
    inputContainerView.addSubview(emailSeparator)
    //x y width height constraint using Snap Kit
    emailSeparator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.left).offset(12)
        make.top.equalTo(emailTextField.snp.bottom)
        make.right.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.right).offset(-12)
        make.height.equalTo(1)
    }

    // constraint for passwordTextField
    inputContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)
    passwordTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.left).offset(12)
        make.top.equalTo(emailSeparator.snp.bottom)
        make.width.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.width)
        make.height.equalTo(inputContainerView.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.333)
    }
```

Here's the image are shown:
[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`remakeConstraints` will remove all previously installed constraints. So, you are probably removing all of the top, leading, and etc contraints and reinstalling just the height. You should use `updateConstraints` or do a remake with all of the declared constraints initially.